# Populate TableView With The Use of PopOverController - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to Populate TableView In PopOverController - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222148/unable-to-populate-tableview-in-popovercontroller-objective-c)

I am using a button called as "button". On clicking it I want to display the contents that are present in my kkkk array in *TableView* with the help of *PopOverController* i.e. I want a small tableView to pop up whose cells show the contents of kkkk array.

I am using the following lines of code ::

```
table = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];

popover2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:table];//Tell which view controller should be shown

[popover2 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)]; // set content size of popover
[popover2 presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:uploadspace permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //From where it should "pop"

self.popoverController = popover2;          
popoverController.delegate = self;

NSString *hhDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *hhFilePath = [hisDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hh.txt"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:hhFilePath ];
kkkk = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    [keys addObjectsFromArray:[dict allkkkk]];


   // NSLog(@"%@ hellooooooooo", [kkkk objectAtIndex:0]);

}
NSLog(@"hiiiiiii");
NSLog(@"%@", [kkkk objectAtIndex:0]);
table.tableView.delegate=self;
table.tableView.delegate = self;


table.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
// Set up the image view and add it to the view but make it hidden
[window addSubview:table.tableView];

//table.hidden = YES;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.table.tableView reloadData];
```

Here, tView is *UITableView* and *table* is *UITableViewController*.

I am able to get the TableView to pop up on the press of my "button'. But, however, I am unable to populate it with the values of my kkkk array. I searched a lot on google as to how to populate a TableView, but to display TableView with the use of PopOverController is different I suppose.

Can anyone help me to sort it out. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I have done that just below the declaration of array .. but still it is not working ..

Comment: @kamalbhai, if its a `UITableViewController` try with `table.tableView.delegate=self` and `table.tableView.datasource=self`

Comment: @iNoob .. I tried that even !! still not working .. now my code is the edited one.

Comment: @kamalbhai, what i suggest is to have a different new class of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` if you use `UIPopOverController`. Because in my experience with popOver i've always used a separate viewcontroller. Wait and watch for any answer, if you don't get any answers try with creating new class. And it's instance in `initWithViewController`.

Comment: hmm .. I think should try a new class of UITableViewController as donw in this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the link below, it may help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
table.dataSource = self;
table.delegate = self;
```

Comment: table is UITableViewController and not UITableView. So, it is showing an error on using yours' lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to set the `DataSource` and `Delegate` of the `TableView` to your `viewController`. And Write the second half of your code in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.