# Unable to Populate TableView In PopOverController - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a `UIButton` called as `UploadButton`. I am using the following lines of code which takes care of the action which should happen on clicking it ::

```
-(IBAction)UploadButtonPressed:(id)sender{  

self.Upload = [[UploadSpaceTableViewController alloc] 
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.UploadTableViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:Upload];               

[self.UploadTableViewPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Here, `UploadSpaceTableViewController` is a separate class which I have made. It has the following functions in it ::

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150.0, 140.0);
self.keys1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[keys1 addObject:@"Red"];
[keys1 addObject:@"Green"];
[keys1 addObject:@"Blue"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [keys1 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

NSString *key1 = [keys1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = key1;

return cell;
}
```

Basically, all I want is to display a `UItableView` inside a `UIPopOverController` on the click of my `UploadButton`.

However, on running the above lines of code I am getting the following erre in gdb ::

```
splitView[4486:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-06-27 14:05:05.531 splitView[4486:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

This is the first time that I am trying to display a `UITableView` inside a `UIPopoverController`. I have tried a lot of variations in the code but, I am unable to sort it out. Can someone help me out ?? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allocated your cell i think by your code it will return nill

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if(cell == nill){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
}     
 // Configure the cell...

 NSString *key1 = [keys1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = key1;

 return cell;
}
```

may this will help you...

Comment: yaaaaa .. I had not allocated my cell. The code now works fine. Thanks a lot. Can you also also explain me the reason ??

Comment: yes if you will not allocate the cell.. then it will return null and then what row would be show??? so at least one cell must return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
self.keys1 = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Your `UploadSpaceTableViewController` has no method setKeys / no property keys.

**Edit for the 2nd error message:**

> UITableView dataSource must return a cell from
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

This means that you should implement the `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //configure your cell here

    return myCongiuredTableViewCell;
}
```

Comment: it has the property keys .. I had not synthesized it before. However, on synthesizing it I get the error as written in my modified code.

Comment: I think I have implemented this method as I have shown in my code.

Comment: is the class where you implemented the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set as your datasource? The error message clearly says that it does not retrieve a UITableViewCell

Comment: I dont think so .. where should I set its datasource ??

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you're passing an invalid argument when you're assigning a value to keys1, `self.keys1 = ...`. If you're, e.g., passing a NSMutableArray to an NSDictionary property, you'll get that error.

Comment: I have defined `keys1` as `NSMutableArray` in my `.h` file. So, I dont think that I am passing an invalid argument in the line that you have mentioned.

Comment: And did you synthesize the property? If you don't synthesize, the compiler won't create the setter method

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if( cell == nil )
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *key1 = [keys1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = key1;

    return cell;

}
```

I think this may helpful for you.